# What type can I use for an Image in my class

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I have the following class in C#:

```
class User
{
  string ID { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  Image Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

The `Image` type is not available in Xamarin.forms in System.Drawing, so what would the correct type be?

**Edit:**
The image will be stored locally on the device's file system or online on AWS S3 storage.

**Edit 2:** The class is contained in a .net standard 2 class library, that I am using as the model in my Xamarin.Forms app. Therefore I cannot use Xamarin.Forms.Image in the library.

Comment: That depends. Where is it coming from? If it's available from the internet it could be a string with a URL. In any case you might want to look at the `ImageSource`, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go another route - byte[], as Xamarin.Forms.Image has a method to load an image from a stream:

```
ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageByteArray));
```

Why did I not go for Splat? It looked very promising, but I have something against external dependencies and the solution seemed quite heavy, especially considering that it is simply for the model.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/):

> `System.Drawing` is not supported in the Unified API for the Xamarin.Mac .NET 4.5 or Mobile frameworks.
>   `System.Drawing` support can be added to iOS and OS X using the [sysdrawing-coregraphics](https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics) library.

Also as a quoted from *Cheesebaron* [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6586/is-system-drawing-imaging-supported):

> If you look at
>   http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/assemblies you
>   will see that `System.Drawing` is not a part of the Assemblies shipped
>   with `Xamarin.Android`, the same goes for `Xamarin.iOS`.
>
> You will need to use the Android counterparts to filter images.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47223787/2946329) by @S.Akbari, `System.Drawing` isn't part of `Xamarin.Android` or `Xamarin.iOS`.  Typically in `Xamarin.Forms` apps, you should use the `Xamarin.Forms.Image` object to show images from the device or from a url source.

Documation can be found [here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/)

Answer (score 0):

try Splat - it has [cross-platform image class](https://github.com/reactiveui/splat). Combine it with [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) to cache images, and voila.